# How to disable mouse acceleration without logging out?

Tags: macos, terminal, mouse, preferences

I know I can type in the terminal:

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1
```

to turn off mouse acceleration **BUT** this requires me to log out and log back in to take effect. The problem is that I'm using a Mac in a network that resets all user preferences every time I log out. So when I log back in, everything is back to default settings. I've tried typing in the terminal:

```
curl -O http://ktwit.net/code/killmouseaccel
chmod +x killmouseaccel
./killmouseaccel mouse
```

which turns off mouse acceleration **but** the problem is that it also resets the tracking speed to very low. If I try to increase the tracking speed in System Preferences, it turns acceleration back on.

Is there a way to disable mouse acceleration without logging out? If not, is there a way to set tracking speed to the max level after using "./killmouseaccel mouse" without turning acceleration back on?

Comment: There is no `killmouseaccel` by default, so this seems to be a custom script. What exactly does it do? And if you are using a mouse anyway, can't you change the tracking speed in Preferences?

Comment: @patrix killmouseaccel completely disables mouse acceleration. When acceleration is disabled, a fast mouse movement moves the cursor just as much as a slow mouse movement. I can change the tracking speed in Preferences, but as I mentioned above, it turns acceleration back on as soon as I adjust it.

Comment: @patrix I read about killmouseaccel in [this site](http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/02/kill-os-x-mouse-acceleration-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: @patrix I edited my post, now I included the whole custom script that kills mouse acceleration. It turns off mouse accel but it resets the tracking speed to a very low setting.